# Can I see what a Python decorator does to my code?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, code-inspection

Is there a way to see what the application of a Python decorator has done with a function to which I have applied it. For example if I have

```
class A(object):

   @property
   def something(self):
       return 0
```

I'd like to see what the code that's executed for `something` actually looks like. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You want to know what `something()` does? It'll throw an exception, because `self` is missing. Or did you  want to know what `property` does? The documentation explains that; the `property` object itself is coded in C.

Comment: Fixed missing `self` (and it's just an example). I'm wondering if there's a general way to see the Python (if any) that the decorator produces.

Comment: A decorator never produces python code. It executes code; the `property` object is callable. `@property` is only syntactic sugar for `something = property(something)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Then I'm really not understanding [this](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/); the example in item 9 in particular.

Comment: `outer(foo)` returns the `inner` function, stored in that example in `decorated`. Thus, calling `decorated()` means you are calling the `nested()` function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So what I'm asking is: is there a way to see the Python code that is no executed when I call  `decorated` — i.e., `inner` with `foo` replacing `some_func`?

Comment: No, there is not. You can step through the process with the debugger, or you can just look at the code yourself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So (continuing with item 9 from the linked article), the general approach would be to see that the decorator produces `outer(foo)` (how do I learn that?), and then look at the source code for `outer` to see what that is.

Comment: That's the part my answer explains. `@<expression>` is syntactic sugar. The `<expression>` is evaluated (it can be more than just a name of a function), and the result is called, passing in the object just below the decorator line. In your example that is `def something()`.

Comment: You then look at the decorator function. What happens when `outer()` is called? It defines a new function object and returns that new function object.

Comment: So, because a decorator is called and the result replaces the original object, `something` is rebound to whatever `outer(something)` returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decorator doesn't produce code; a decorator is really only syntactic sugar:

```
@property
def something(self):
    return 42
```

is really interpreted as:

```
def something(self):
    return 42
something = property(something)
```

e.g. the expression following the `@` sign is evaluated, and the result is called, passing in the function or class following the `@` line. Whatever the decorator then returns *replaces* the original object.

For introspection purposes, the `@` line is *not* retained; you'd have to parse the source code itself to discover any decorators present. A decorator is not obliged to return a new object; you can return the original object unaltered and you cannot, with introspection, know the difference.

Your best bet is to return to the source of the decorator then and just read the code. The `property` decorator is implemented in C, but the [descriptor howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties) contains a Python implementation that does the same thing:

```
class Property(object):
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
```